# How do I add an error message to a question box?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, tkinter

I am trying to make a revision material for classmates, and I have a list of terms for OCR Computer Science, in a dictionary named "my_dict". However, if a term is entered incorrectly, it just sends an error message to the Python shell. If anyone can help me add an error message to the code provided, that would be much appreciated.

I have tried basic if, while, next loops, but to no avail.

```
def button_click():
    typed_text = (entry1.get()).lower()
    output_text.delete(0.0, END)
    if typed_text is in my_dict{}:
        meaning = my_dict[(typed_text)]
    else:
        meaning = str("Are you sure you entered the term correctly?"
    output_text.insert(END, meaning)
```

I expect the output to fill the output box with the error message "Are you sure you entered the term correctly?", but the actual output is an invalid syntax currently.

Comment: Is this your actual code? You're missing a parenthesis. Also, `my_dict{}` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_dict{}` is not a valid syntax, you just have to pass `my_dict` for the `in` expression. `is in` is also not valid syntax, so just use `in`

In the `str("Are you sure you entered the term correctly?"` you are missing a paranthese at the end.

There are some spots where you don't need extra parantheses. Ditch them in `(entry1.get())` and `[(typed_text)]`